# CSS Import Font doesn’t work on live server but works on jsfiddle

Tags: html, css, import, fonts, font-face

I’m trying to import custom font on my web page but I see no change on live server, when I’m trying my code on jsfiddle everything works perfectly.
I was trying to disable cache but it doesn’t work also.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>The 2021 Frontend Developer Crash Course</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="logo" href="#">Remember<span>That</span></a>

            <img id="mobile-cta" class="mobile-menu" src="images/menu.svg" alt="Open Navigation">

            <nav>
                <img id="mobile-exit" class="mobile-menu-exit" src="images/exit.svg" alt="Close Navigation">

                <ul class="primary-nav">
                    <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="secondary-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="go-premium-cta"><a href="#">Go Premiuim</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <section class="hero">
        <div class="cointaner">
            <div class="left-col">
                <p class="subhead">It's Nitty &amp; Gritty</p>
                <h1>A Task App That Doesn't Stink</h1>

                <div class="hero-cta">
                    <a href="#" class="primary-cta">Try for free</a>
                    <a href="#" class="watch-video-cta">
                        <img src="images/watch.svg" alt="Watch a video">Watch a video
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <img src="images/illustration.svg" class="hero-img" alt="Illustration">
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="features-section">
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li>Unlimited Tasks</li>
                <li>SMS Task Reminders</li>
                <li>Confetti Explosions upon Task Completions</li>
                <li>Real Time Collaboration</li>
                <li>Other awesome features</li>
            </ul>
            <img src="images/holding-phone.jpg" alt="Man holding phone">
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="testimonials-section">
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="images/person.jpg" alt="Person">
                    <blockquote>"Lorem ipsum"</blockquote>
                    <cite>- Jane Doe</cite>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <img src="images/person.jpg" alt="Person">
                    <blockquote>"Lorem ipsum"</blockquote>
                    <cite>- Jane Doe</cite>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <img src="images/person.jpg" alt="Person">
                    <blockquote>"Lorem ipsum"</blockquote>
                    <cite>- Jane Doe</cite>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <section class="contact-sesion">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="contact-left">
                <h2>Contact</h2>
                
                <form action="">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">

                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
               
                    <input type="submit" class="send-message-cta" value="Send message">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="contact-right">
                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d39266.193138783136!2d15.065798207389161!3d52.0408164098161!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x470637afdce9dd61%3A0x56bc8ba3e28c3293!2s66-600%20Krosno%20Odrza%C5%84skie!5e0!3m2!1spl!2spl!4v1647988503628!5m2!1spl!2spl" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap');

body {
    background: #F2F2F2;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; !important;
}

.navbar {
    background: white;
    padding: 1em;

    .logo {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: black;
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
```

[image: output]

I tried:

- changing browsers
- adding !important
- changing font
- adding font from local
- deleting cache

Comment: Does it reach the CSS file or do you maybe have a problem with you linked CSS file? In your screenshot it seems as if the CSS is not working.

Comment: Can you give us the link to the live site?  It appears that it's most likely a path issue - for example, your CSS is not in the right place on the server.